# SWIFT... how to loop through UIcollectionView, and getting values from the textfield into an array

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uicollectionview, viewwithtag

so i have given the textfields a tag of 10 i want to loop through the cells of the collection view  and get the values of the textfield and store them into an array... here is some code.......

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell1 =  collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    let textbox1 = cell1?.viewWithTag(10) as? UITextField

    print(indexPath.row)

print(textbox1?.text)

}
```

if I select the cell the right text is shown, I will eventually have a button, when clicked id want it to loop though all of the cells and store it into an array(which i can do). i need a way to loop through the cells using the index path and storing the textfield data, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

> But it only give visible Cells textField values

```
for item in self.collectionView!.visibleCells() as! [CollectionViewCell] {
        var indexpath : NSIndexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(item as CollectionViewCell)!
        var cell : CollectionViewCell = self.collectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexpath) as! CollectionViewCell
        println(cell.textField1.text)
    }
```

**Method 2:**

globally declare a mutableArray

```
var arrayCellsTextFields : NSMutableArray = []
```

in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
cell.textField1.tag  = indexPath.row;
if(arrayCellsTextFields .containsObject(cell.textField1)==false)
{
   arrayCellsTextFields .addObject(cell.textField1)
}
```

Array contain ur textFields object, you can identify the textfield with its tag, i.e., `cell.textField1.tag` & `indexPath.row` are same

**Method 3:**

in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
cell.textField1.tag  = indexPath.row;
cell.textField1.delegate = self;
```

using the textField delegate `textFieldDidEndEditing` u will get values in textField